# Gauge invariance based on exact global symmetries

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, gauge-theory, noethers-theorem, gauge-invariance

In Peskin and Schroeder there is a passage that states

> "*Since the construction of a theory with gauge invariance is based on the existence of an exact global symmetry, the violation of the conservation of $j^{\mu a}$ does violence to the structure of the theory*".

I am having difficulty with the first part of this sentence. I understand the difference between gauge and global symmetries but how is the gauge invariant theory construction relying on an exact global symmetry?

Comment: How could it fail that? Gauging *means* promoting a global symmetry to a local one (gauge) through gauge fields.

Comment: Is that what they meant? Then I'm just over thinking this.